# Cairo-dock only shows one workspace after upgrade to 14.04 LTS

Tags: workspaces, cairo-dock, workspace-switcher

I have a Linux desktop that I try to keep up to date, although I don't use it a lot.  I had it configured with cairo-dock, showing 2x2 workspaces.  It's been like this for quite a while.  I recently upgraded to 14.04 LTS, and now the switcher only shows a single workspace.  I read several posts that talk about similar problems, but I wasn't able to get a viable clue.

What can I look at to get some clues?

Comment: I believe by default workspaces are disabled. You probably just need to enable them

Comment: And I do that how?

Comment: Ah. Finally found it.  In Settings->Appearance->Behavior.  I have no idea why someone thought this should be in "Behavior" instead of "Look".

Comment: @Elefantphace that is incredibly unhelpful advice! Come on, this is quite a confusing thing to find; just explain how, or if you don't know, ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

As @ElefantPhace pointed out, workspaces are apparently disabled by default (although that results in having a single workspace).  This is fixed by going to "System Settings...", then "Appearance", then "Behavior", then turning on the "Enable workspace" flag.